# Adding a UITextView and scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:
                        [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 100, 200, 250)];
    textView .text =@"long text ";
```

I will be getting some data of unknown length. to be added to the `UITextView` . Sometimes the height of the content of the text might exceed the height of the `UITextView` which is `250` (shown above).

How can i increase the height of the `UITextView` based on the text i receive ? I would appreciate a sample code? Later i need to add this to a `UIScrollView` (i know how to add to a scrollview), but again i don't know how to increase the height of the scrollview. Can someone help me code this ?

note: according to my code i am defining the `width` and `height` of the `UITextView` before adding the text to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. When the text content grows larger than the frame of the text view, the content will automatically begin to scroll. There is no need to embed a `UITextView` in a `UIScrollView` because it already is one (and more!).

Answer (score 0):

Set the size of textView equal to it's contentSize.
The scrollView you have to set it's contentSize equal to the size you want.